# uploading image using ImageField in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, imagefield

I am trying to upload files using Django's ImageField and forms everytime I click submit on the form. The **form.is_valid** returns **false**
So I printed forms.errors
It says

```
photo2
This field is required.

photo1
This field is required.
```

I select the image files I want to upload and it still says field is required.

Here is view of my **settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Here is **views.py**

```
 def upload(request):
 if request.method=="POST":
     prod = Product()
     form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
     if form.is_valid():
         prod.name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')
         prod.brand = form.cleaned_data.get('brand')
         prod.material = form.cleaned_data.get('material')
         prod.color = form.cleaned_data.get('color')
         prod.price = form.cleaned_data.get('price')
         prod.discount = form.cleaned_data.get('discount')
         prod.sex=form.cleaned_data.get('sex')
         prod.photo1 = form.cleaned_data('photo1')
         prod.photo2 = form.cleaned_data('photo2')
         prod.save()
         return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
     else:
         x = form.errors
         return render(request,'upload.html', {'alert':x}, {'form': form})

 else:
     form = UploadForm
     return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

Here is my **models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='N/A')
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='N/A')
    material = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='N/A')
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='N/A')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    discountprice = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    photo1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='productphotos/')
    photo2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='productphotos/')

    Male = 'M'
    Female = 'F'
    Both = 'Both'

    Genders = ((Male, 'Male'),(Female, 'Female'), (Both, 'Both'))
    sex = models.CharField(choices=Genders, default=Male, max_length=6)
```

**forms.py**
    class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

```
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'brand', 'material', 'sex', 'color', 'price', 'discount', 'photo1', 'photo2']
```

and in my **template**
I am just using

```
<div>
 {{form}}
</div>
```

Thank you for help in advance. I can upload forms.py if needed.

Comment: where is your UploadForm code?

Comment: DId you add the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute to the `form` tag in your template?

Comment: @schwobaseggl I uploaded my template code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the form markup in the template as it is not included when rendering `{{ form }}`:

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}  # if needed
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

The `enctype="multipart/form-data"` is essential when posting files from the form. See the [docs on forms in general](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/#the-template) and those on [file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/) in particular:

> Note that request.FILES will only contain data if the request method was POST and the form that posted the request has the attribute enctype="multipart/form-data". Otherwise, request.FILES will be empty.

Comment: I did it and now I get a new error saying `'dict' object not callable` on line `prod.photo1 = form.cleaned_data('photo1')`

Comment: You are missing `.get()`